# Unable to set width inside ASP repeater

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am having below repeater with table tr and td I have assigned width to these but that doesn't work. I have tried with px and % both doesn't work in my case.

```
 <div style="padding: 3px;">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptIncrementalInt" runat="server" Visible="true" OnItemDataBound="rptIncrementalInt_ItemDataBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="ey-dataTable">
                                <tbody style="background-color: white">
                                    <tr class="Heading">
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 5% !Important;" rowspan="2">Company Group</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 50px;" rowspan="2">Entity</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 50px;" rowspan="2">Category</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 40px;" rowspan="2">Legislation</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 40px;" rowspan="2">Nature of Proceeding</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px" rowspan="2">Interest Type</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 40px;" rowspan="2">Section</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Rate (%)</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 40px;" rowspan="2">Mode of interest computation</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Start Date Type</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Start Date dd-mmm-yy</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 40px;" rowspan="2">End Date dd-mmm-yy</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Adjustment for part of the month</td>

                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">No. of days in a month</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">No. of days in a year</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Amount on which Int to be computed</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Net Amount</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 90px;" colspan="3">Break-up, if available</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Interest compounded on</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 60px;" colspan="2">Period</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;" rowspan="2">Interest</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 90px;" colspan="3">Existing Open Issues</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 90px;" colspan="3">Risk Apportionment</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="Heading AlignedRow">
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px">Base Exposure</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px">Interest</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px">Penalty</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px">Month</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px">Days</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;">Probable</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;">Possible</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;">Remote</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;">Probable</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;">Possible</td>
                                        <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" style="width: 30px;">Remote</td>
                                    </tr>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 50px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CGroupName") %>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddMainProceedingId" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"MainProceedingId") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddRowIndex" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"RoWID") %>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddInterestCalcId" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"InterestCalcId") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 50px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EntityName") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 50px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 40px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Legislation") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 40px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NOP") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;">
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestType") %>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddInterestTypeID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"InterestTypeID") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 40px;">
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SectionRef") %>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddSecRefID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SectionRefID") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IntRate") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 40px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IntModeComputation") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDateType") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 40px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EndDate") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AdjPartOfMonth") %></td>

                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NoOfDaysMonths") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 40px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NoOfDaysYr") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 40px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AmtIntComputatedOn") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right; width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NetAmt") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right; width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DutyAmt") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right; width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InterestAmt") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right; width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PenaltyAmt") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInterestComputedOn" Width="90px" CssClass="Amount" OnKeyUp="javascript:NumberWithCommas(this, this.value);"
                                        runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IntComputatedOn") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reAmount" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtInterestComputedOn"
                                        ErrorMessage='<%# String.Format("Please Enter Only Numbers in Interest Computed On in Row No {0}", Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>' CssClass="errors"
                                        ValidationExpression1="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"
                                        ValidationExpression="^(?:\d|[,])+$" ValidationGroup="Main">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </td>

                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PeriodMonth") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PeriodDays") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtInterest" runat="server" Width="90px" CssClass="Amount" OnKeyUp="javascript:NumberWithCommas(this, this.value);"
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Interest") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reInterest" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtInterest"
                                        ErrorMessage='<%# String.Format("Please Enter Only Numbers in Interest in Row No {0}", Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>' CssClass="errors"
                                        ValidationExpression="^(?:\d|[,])+$" ValidationGroup="Main">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                </td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Probable") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Possible") %></td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Remote") %></td>

                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRiskProbable" runat="server" Width="90px" CssClass="Amount" OnKeyUp="javascript:NumberWithCommas(this, this.value);"
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProbableApp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reRiskProbable" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRiskProbable"
                                        ErrorMessage='<%# String.Format("Please Enter Only Numbers in Risk Probable in Row No {0}", Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>' CssClass="errors"
                                        ValidationExpression="^(?:\d|[,])+$" ValidationGroup="Main">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                                </td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRiskPossible" runat="server" Width="90px" CssClass="Amount" OnKeyUp="javascript:NumberWithCommas(this, this.value);"
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PossibleApp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reRiskPossible" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRiskPossible"
                                        ErrorMessage='<%# String.Format("Please Enter Only Numbers in Risk Possible in Row No {0}", Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>' CssClass="errors"
                                        ValidationExpression="^(?:\d|[,])+$" ValidationGroup="Main">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                                </td>
                                <td class="ey-formlabel1" style="width: 30px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRiskRemote" runat="server" Width="90px" CssClass="Amount" OnKeyUp="javascript:NumberWithCommas(this, this.value);"
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RemoteApp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reRiskRemote" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtRiskRemote"
                                        ErrorMessage='<%# String.Format("Please Enter Only Numbers in Risk Remote in Row No {0}", Container.ItemIndex + 1) %>' CssClass="errors"
                                        ValidationExpression="^(?:\d|[,])+$" ValidationGroup="Main">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <tr class="Heading" style="text-align: justify; font-weight: bolder;">
                                <td colspan="21">&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Total
                                </td>
                                <td class="Heading ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td class="Heading ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRiskProbableTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="Heading ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRiskPossibleTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="Heading ey-formlabel1" style="text-align: right;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRiskRemoteTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody> </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>

                    <div style="padding: 3px;">
                        <table width="99%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="ey-dataTable">
                            <tbody style="background-color: white">
                                <tr class="Heading">
                                    <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" rowspan="2" style="width: 600px;">test by Nadeem 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow" colspan="2" style="width: 5px;">test by Nadeem 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="ey-formlabel1 AlignedRow">Pending
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ey-formlabel1">Item</td>
                                    <td class="ey-formlabel1">Item1</td>
                                    <td class="ey-formlabel1">Item2</td>
                                    <td class="ey-formlabel1">Item3</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div id="divIntNoRecGrid" runat="server" visible="false" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; margin-top: 20px; color: Red;">
                        No Record(s) found...
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px;" id="divPaging" runat="server">
                        <table style="width: 400px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbFirst" Text="| < First" runat="server"
                                        OnClick="lbFirst_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPrevious" runat="server"
                                        OnClick="lbPrevious_Click" Text="| << Previous"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbNext" runat="server"
                                        OnClick="lbNext_Click" Text="| Next >> |"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLast" runat="server"
                                        OnClick="lbLast_Click" Text="Last > |"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblpage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div style="overflow: hidden; display: none;">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptPaging" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptPaging_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPage"
                                    Style="padding: 8px; margin: 2px; background: gray; border: solid 1px #666; font: 8pt tahoma;"
                                    CommandName="Page" OnClientClick="ShowProgress();" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>"
                                    runat="server" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True"><%# Container.DataItem %>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My css classes are like below:

```
    .ey-dataTable
{
    background-color: rgb(219,221,221); 
    width: 99.5%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.ey-formlabel1
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    vertical-align: top;
}   
.AlignedRow
        {
            vertical-align: top;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what is wrong, but I can give you a few pointers:

First problem is with the header. You have a row span. But the rows you are spanning together have different width. You can't be sure how the browsers will react to that.

Second. It is best to not mix %  and px. The results will vary depending on screen width.

A tip: only set widths on your very first row. That is enough and makes your live alot easier for finding out where it goes wrong. You don't need the width definition on each row. 1 row will do just fine.

I hope this will nod you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Thor, As per your instrunction I have given width in % only and also width is given only to first row, But problem still persist.